# What is a security checklist to go through before making your GAE app public?

Tags: google-app-engine

Particularly interested in App Engine related measures.

Comment: This is really too vague to answer sensibly and concretely. There aren't really "App Engine related measures" beyond what's a good idea for all webapps.

Answer (score 1):

Not striving for completeness, but you might want to avoid using urlsafe-encoded keys in URLs or as hidden form fields, since knowledgeable users can easily decode these and possibly construct ones that they shouldn't be allowed to access.

You might also want to audit your app.yaml file to make sure that the http and login settings are as they should be, e.g. admin-only pages are protected with login:admin (and probably admin pages should require http).

Other responders might have specific suggestions for issues concerning the webapp framework.